# Ampersand help in an article from a SharePoint Novice

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have an article I need to post on my company intranet that we use SharePoint.  I need to put a company name that has the ampersand sign in the title.  Is this possible?  I tried a few codes that I saw on here but with no luck.

It's a simple question but I have no clue how to properly do this.  I know the ampersand sign is not recognized in SharePoint but is that just in code or anywhere in the program?  Any and all help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I've tried to insert "&" symbol into a Title field and it works just fine. I've also managed to easily put it right on the publishing page. Can you, please, specify where exactly "the ampersand sign is not recognized in SharePoint"?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?  As Zerg said you should be able to do this although ampersands do not play well with query string filters.

Comment: Forgive me as I am such a novice...I am trying to upload a photo and type in the Story section.  I need a include a title that has the ampersand sign but when I hit save, it shows up as amp; in the body of the text.  I read on this forum earlier that the ampersand sign is not something SharePoint recognizes.